# $\gamma \in C^{\infty}(U, \mathbb{R}^n)$ is an Open Map

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $U$ is ***open***. Let $\gamma \in C^{\infty}(U, \mathbb{R}^n)$ an injective continuous map with the property that $\gamma(U) =V $ and $\gamma: U \to V$ is a ***diffeomorphism***.

Is then $V$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$? If yes, why?

Consideration: Surely, since $\gamma$ is a diffeomorphsim in $C^{\infty}(U, V)$, it is there a homeomorphism and therefore there an open map. But here we consider $V= \gamma(U)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. How to see that $\gamma(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: It seems that from your hypothesesit follows that $\gamma^{-1}(V) = U$, so that $V$ is indeed open.

Comment: @Hugo: Why? We can only define the inverse map $\gamma^{-1}:C^{\infty}(V = \gamma(U) , U)$. But this just states the trivial fact that $V$ is open in $V$. The question was why $V$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.